# R gsub( ) , Regular Expression

Tags: regex, r

I have the following data

```
Names[]
[1] John Simon is a great player
[2] Chi-Twi is from china
[3] O'Konnor works hard
[4] R.F is a swimmer
```

I need to extract only the names from all these rows and store them. I tried doing it this way.

```
[1] John Simon 
[2] Chi-Twi 
[3] O'Konnor 
[4] R.F 

names = gsub("(^[A-Z|a-z|.|-|']+[ ]+[A-Z|a-z|.|-|]+)[ ]+.*", "\\1",names)
```

can some one help me out?

Comment: This is going to be difficult because how do you know `works` or `is` isn't a last name?

Comment: Let's say we just have to extract the first two words??

Comment: First 2 words: `^\w+\W\w+` or `^\w+\W+\w+`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that will work for this sample data:

```
names = gsub("(^[A-Za-z]+[^A-Za-z][A-Za-z]+)", "\\1", names)
```

If underscores are valid characters in a first or last name, you could shorten it to:

```
names = gsub("(^\\w+\\W\\w+)", "\\1", names)
```

It simply takes one or more letters, a non-letter, and then one or more letters again.

Some things I noticed wrong in your regex:

`[A-Z|a-z|.|-|']+` actually matches `A-Z`, `|`, `a-z`, `|` (again), `.`, `|-|` (that's a range), and `'`. You really wanted `[A-Za-z.\\-']+`.

In any case, that's wrong, you don't want to include dots or dashes in the first name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @nhahtdh's comment, you can use

```
sub("(^\\w+\\W\\w+).*", "\\1", Names)
# [1] "John Simon" "Chi-Twi"    "O'Konnor"   "R.F"
```